# Shiny Apps Error in R Studio

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny, shinydashboard

My Shiny apps had been running fine until last week.
I am trying to run the apps today and getting errors in most of them :
Below is the error and my sessionInfo.

I am using Shinydashboard and other shiny libraries to render an app.

```
Error in withReactiveDomain(shinysession, { : 
No handler registered for for type file1:shiny.file



sessionInfo()

R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.1 (Yosemite)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats4    grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils        datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] locfit_1.5-9.1                          ggbiplot_0.55                           scales_0.4.0                           
[4] chimera_1.14.0                          Homo.sapiens_1.3.1                      org.Hs.eg.db_3.3.0                     
[7] GO.db_3.3.0                             OrganismDbi_1.14.1                      TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene_3.2.2
[10] GenomicFeatures_1.24.5                  BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19_1.4.0       BSgenome_1.40.1                        
[13] rtracklayer_1.32.2                      AnnotationDbi_1.34.4                    GenomicAlignments_1.8.4                
[16] Rsamtools_1.24.0                        Biostrings_2.40.2                       XVector_0.12.1                         
[19] BiocInstaller_1.22.3                    gTrack_0.1.0                            gUtils_0.2.0                           
[22] data.table_1.9.6                        stringr_1.1.0                           devtools_1.12.0                        
[25] reshape_0.8.5                           DESeq2_1.12.4                           SummarizedExperiment_1.2.3             
[28] Biobase_2.32.0                          GenomicRanges_1.24.3                    GenomeInfoDb_1.8.7                     
[31] IRanges_2.6.1                           S4Vectors_0.10.3                        BiocGenerics_0.18.0                    
[34] xlsx_0.5.7                              xlsxjars_0.6.1                          rJava_0.9-8                            
[37] shinydashboard_0.5.3                    DT_0.2                                  shiny_0.14.1                           
[40] ggplot2_2.1.0                           sva_3.20.0                              genefilter_1.54.2                      
[43] mgcv_1.8-15                             nlme_3.1-128                            matrixStats_0.51.0                     
[46] pvclust_2.0-0                           gplots_3.0.1                            reshape2_1.4.1                         
[49] plyr_1.8.4                              ComplexHeatmap_1.11.7                  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] colorspace_1.2-7     rjson_0.2.15         class_7.3-14            modeltools_0.2-21    mclust_5.2          
[6] circlize_0.3.9       GlobalOptions_0.0.10 flexmix_2.3-13       mvtnorm_1.0-5        splines_3.3.1       
[11] robustbase_0.92-6    geneplotter_1.50.0   Formula_1.2-1        jsonlite_1.1         annotate_1.50.1     
 [16] cluster_2.0.5        kernlab_0.9-25       graph_1.50.0         httr_1.2.1           Matrix_1.2-7.1      
 [21] acepack_1.3-3.3      htmltools_0.3.5      tools_3.3.1          gtable_0.2.0         Rcpp_0.12.7         
[26] trimcluster_0.1-2    gdata_2.17.0         fpc_2.1-10           mime_0.5             gtools_3.5.0        
[31] XML_3.98-1.4         dendextend_1.3.0     DEoptimR_1.0-6       zlibbioc_1.18.0      MASS_7.3-45         
[36] RBGL_1.48.1          RColorBrewer_1.1-2   yaml_2.1.13          curl_2.1             memoise_1.0.0       
[41] gridExtra_2.2.1      biomaRt_2.28.0       rpart_4.1-10         latticeExtra_0.6-28  stringi_1.1.2       
[46] RSQLite_1.0.0        caTools_1.17.1       BiocParallel_1.6.6   shape_1.4.2          chron_2.3-47        
 [51] prabclus_2.2-6       bitops_1.0-6         lattice_0.20-34      htmlwidgets_0.7      labeling_0.3        
[56] magrittr_1.5         R6_2.2.0             Hmisc_3.17-4         DBI_0.5-1            whisker_0.3-2       
[61] foreign_0.8-67       withr_1.0.2          survival_2.39-5      RCurl_1.95-4.8       nnet_7.3-12         
[66] KernSmooth_2.23-15   GetoptLong_0.1.5     git2r_0.15.0         digest_0.6.10        diptest_0.75-7      
[71] xtable_1.8-2         httpuv_1.3.3         munsell_0.4.3
```

Any idea,what this could be?

Thanks,

Ron

Answer (score 0):

Shiny version `0.14.2` was published last week (along with new versions of `R` and `RStudio`). Maybe this broke something in your code. One way to protect against this is to use something like `packrat` package that locks in a certain version of an `R` package so that your code is not changed by a new package. You can then test your code against an upgrade and troubleshoot before using that new version.

Comment: To lock it is doing > packrat::init("~/projects/..")   enough ?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting R studio worked.There was no need to update any packages.